# App version from Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current - WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, version

Even though I have an app version set as 3.0.4 both in WMAppManifest as Package.appxmanifest, `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current` gives me 1.0.0.0

Any clues? This is how I'm trying to retrieve

```
var myPackage = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
var ver = myPackage.Id.Version;
string appVer = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", ver.Major, ver.Minor, ver.Build, ver.Revision);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have WMAppManifest in your project, your app is a Silverlight one, so the best way si to parse the WMAppManifest file and get the version from there, here is a sample: https://github.com/igorkulman/Kulman.WP8/blob/master/Kulman.WP8/Code/ManifestHelper.cs

Answer (score 0):

You can set your app version in the AssemblyInfo.cs file like this :

`[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]`

To retrieve it do this :

```
var nameHelper = new AssemblyName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
string sMyAppVersion = nameHelper.Version.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a 8.1 universal app. Go to Package.appxmanifest file and click the packaging tab. There you can verify what values you are passing for Version (Major, Minor,Build,Revision)

Hope this helps.